# Found iclouddnsbypass.com pop-up when connected to personal hotspot

Tags: icloud, wifi, macos

Today I'm trying to connect to my personal hotspot but a iclouddnsbypass.com pop-up appeared, the device is connected to WiFi but no internet connection.

My question is what is iclouddnsbypass.com and how it can be appeared on my mac even though I never install their apps. Could be someone trying to gain access to my WiFi using this tool?

Found similar situation https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7694703 but no answers.

Comment: Your personal hotspot is your own or from somebody else?

Comment: It was my personal hotspot. It always on and never power it off even I'm not at home.

Comment: it has something todo with your DNS settings. Try to reset your hotspot.. They don't have apps. They want you to edit DNS settings on your phone.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I have this same issue now on my Mac. I don't think it's the hotspot, since connecting to captive.apple.com from another phone will not trigger the redirection

Comment: I have the same issue when tethering from my Android - must have installed a dodgy app. Any ideas which one to nuke? Weird because seems to be a DNS change but my phone is NOT rooted and https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tetheringhotspot-in-android says it's not possible to change DNS when tethered....